# Can an Alexa Trigger send variables to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am starting to work with Alexa Skills and have already created a AWS Lambda that has cloudwatch triggers, each trigger has a specific variable that is used when the lambda runs (E.G, country of IE will run the lambda using IE as a key.)

I now want to call the AWS Lambda via an Alexa skill but i want to pass the specific key. (E.G, Alexa run the IE feed.)

The documentation i found only documents how to trigger the lambda, not trigger it and passing a variable.

Can this be done? Or is a skill only able to trigger a lambda?

Answer (score 0):

The only interface is really the defined [JSON interface](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html).
So I don't see a chance to add additional things to it.

What do you mean with country for IE? For me IE always means internet explorer but that's for sure not the right translation here ;-).

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained better. The lambda is a product feed generator, and used a country key to get the products in a specific country. So IE means the Irish Products.

Comment: ah ok. Than you could maybe use the `locale` https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#request-locale. Or need to get this information from a slot filled by the customer. Or your store this information in some DB depending on the user or whatever. How do you decide which country key? You are talking about a custom skill, right?

Comment: I have a cloudWatch event on my lambda that has a schedule like this:

Comment: schedule:
          name: "Shopfeed-IE"
          description: "Run the IE shopfeed xml generation at 00:00 AM Irish Time Every day"
          enabled: true
          rate: cron(59 23 * * ? *)
          input:
            key: 'IE'

Comment: And the input: key: IE is used in the lambda when invoked. (This is 23 other scheduled events that invoke the lambda with a different Key. ) I want to create an Alexa Skill to run the IE feed.

Comment: ah ok. So you are talking about 2 thing. The lambda as backend for your alexa skill and the lambda for your feed creation. You thought you could combine this but this isn't working I suppose (both have 2 different interfaces). So I would create my alexa backend lambda and insight this lambda you can trigger an other lambda (feed generator) with your key.